# Dismiss BlockUI on click outside element

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

I'm using BlockUI block a page. The element used by BlockUI covers the lower half of the page. Although I have a close button on the element, which works just fine, I alos need to unblock if there is a click in the are above my element. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you post your codes too, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/BheGf/)***

I have come across a similar need before. You will need to know the layer that the BlockUI is on. I will assume that it has a z-index of 10. What you are going to want to do here is set an invisible layer beneath it and then attach a click event there which will tie into the close event already on your blockui element.

```
.clr{
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 z-index:5;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
}
```